# woocommerce create a user on guest checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am using Woocommerce guest checkout and all my customers have 0 id. As I have to export the orders and need different ids for each customer for the report, I need to automatically create either a user for each customer or assign an id for each customer (maybe differentiate them via email). Is there a way I can achieve one of these solutions?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, just added `<p class="form-row form-row-wide create-account">
        <input style="display: none" class="input-checkbox" id="createaccount" checked type="checkbox" name="createaccount" value="1" />
    </p>`
hidden checkbox, which automatically created user with role of customer for every guest.